# IRegisteredObject not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0, appdomain

#### Background

I'm working on an ASP.NET 4 web site (not web application). I'm trying to use `IRegisteredObject` to allow some long-running code to run in a non-request thread.

For testing, I've set the IIS 7.5 application pool's recycle interval to low values so that it will try to recycle while the background thread is running.

#### Code

```
public class AspFriendlyBackgroundJob
{
    private readonly object key = new object();
    private readonly Task task;

    public AspFriendlyBackgroundJob(Action work)
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(new Stopper(this));
            task = Task.Factory.StartNew(work);
        }
    }

    class Stopper : IRegisteredObject
    {
        private readonly AspFriendlyBackgroundJob job;

        public Stopper(AspFriendlyBackgroundJob job)
        {
            this.job = job;
        }

        public void Stop(bool immediate)
        {
            lock (job.key)
            {
                job.task.Wait();
                HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Problem

When the application pool was recycled, `IRegisteredObject.Stop` was called with `immediate` set to `false`. However, the process appears to terminate before `Stop` returns; the call to `HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject` never gets reached. This behaviour seems contrary to the following information I read:

[Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html):

> - If there are still registered objects running after 30 seconds, ASP.NET will call `IRegisteredObject.Stop(true)` on them.
> - ASP.NET will unload the AppDomain after all those second notifications have returned.

[Performing Asynchronous Work, or Tasks, in ASP.NET Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx):

> If you need to, you can hold up the unload as long as you like, because we won’t unload until your Stop method returns the second time.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I'm trying to understand how to use `IRegisteredObject` correctly.

Comment: @DanielLidström, I ended up concluding that the behaviour I saw was just normal. For my situation, I decided that `IRegisteredObject` wasn't suitable for running long-running background work, so I decided to just use a separate process (a console app) to do the background work instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I agree, if you can you should use a separate process for these things. Anyway, thanks for sharing.

Comment: check this article: https://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/

Answer (score 2):

Actually, IRegisteredObject works as expected. What I guess is happening to you is that your task might take more than the default 90 seconds in the "Shutdown Time Limit" IIS AppPool setting. In that case, the worker process will be forcibly killed. So it's not aspnet that's killing the process, but rather IIS. Modifying the Shutdown Time Limit should fix the problem, just take care it doesn't cause any trouble as you'll have more instances of the worker process alive (but the old one will be only processing the Stop() method, it won't handle new requests).

Comment: I've noticed that if a docker 'stop' command triggers the shutdown, IRegisteredObject is only called with (immediate:true). It's never called with (immediate:false). No idea why. Maybe it's related to this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36089